# Which one is right? "person guilty" vs "guilty person"?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, nouns

In the book of "1100 Words You Need to Know", about "felon" word, the following definition was presented:

> "person guilty of a major crime"

I am wondering the following one should be right:

> "guilty person of a major crime"

In fact, "guilty" is adjective of "person" as a noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjectives (or adject participles) precede the noun unless they are modified by objects: the guilty person, the running person, the convicted person; but not *the guilty of the crime person, *the running away person, *the convicted by the jury person.  In those cases, we use a [highly reduced] relative clause to move the complex adject phrase: the person [that is/was] guilty of the crime, the person [that is/was] running away, the person [that was] convicted by the jury.  (The words in [ ] can be omitted.)

Do not try to separate the object of the adject -- it has a different meaning when it modifies the noun: *the guilty person of the crime, *the running person away, *the convicted person by the jury.